# Wrong "user" being returned

Tags: arrays, json

In this part of my code, the return statement at the bottom is returning the returnedUser = null instead of the returnedUser = new User(user.username, name, sex, age, user.password);

Any ideas of why this is happening? Shouldn't the second returnedUser = new User overwrite the returnedUser = null?

I ran it in debug mode and it is hitting the else statement and the returnedUser is being updated to the correct info but when it hits the return returnedUser statement at the end it is returning returnedUser = null.

```
User returnedUser = null;
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if(jObject.length() == 0){
                user = null;
            }else{
                String name = jObject.getString("name");
                String sex = jObject.getString("sex");
                int age = jObject.getInt("age");

                returnedUser = new User(user.username, name, sex, age, user.password);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        return returnedUser;
    }

public class User {

String username, name, sex, password;
int age;

public User (String username, String name, String sex, int age,
             String password){

    this.username = username;
    this.name = name;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.age = age;
    this.password = password;
}

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = "";
    this.sex = "N/A";
    this.age = -1;
}

}
```

Comment: Is 'new User' throwing an exception?

Comment: no when I run it in debug I can see the new User's info and it is all correct info from that user coming from the database. do you want me to post the output of debug step by step?

Comment: Where is the variable user declared at? It seems like if what you are saying is true then something is missing.

Comment: I just added the User class to the question

Comment: OMG, just use a debugger and step though your code.

Comment: That is what I am doing. Thank you for the non-useful advice, couldn't do it without you bhspencer.